# Is there a way to disable the DHCP client in Raspbian Linux on a Rasperry Pi?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, ip-address

I have a Linux server (Rasperry Pi using Raspbian as OS) that should be using only static IP.

However I noticed that it also has got IP from DHCP server (The IP given out by DHCP is `192.168.111.2`). According to network settings the server should be only using static IP (`192.168.111.100`).

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.111.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.111.1
dns-nameservers ip1 ip2
```

Despite using static configuration I can SSH to the device also using the IP given by DHCP. Also it appears that `ntpd` is using the wrong IP as well as the correct one.

Output of Netstat:

```
udp        0      0 192.168.111.2:123       0.0.0.0:*                           2774/ntpd
udp        0      0 192.168.111.100:123     0.0.0.0:*                           2774/ntpd
```

According to `ifconfig` the IP `192.168.111.2` is not used:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:be:18:1c
          inet addr:192.168.111.100  Bcast:192.168.111.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:138099 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:81146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:95954711 (91.5 MiB)  TX bytes:27076870 (25.8 MiB)
```

`ps -ef | grep dhcp` shows that I have a DHCP daemon running:

```
root      2000     1  0 Oct07 ?        00:00:06 /sbin/dhcpcd
```

How do I disable the `DHCP` daemon from starting and make sure that my server uses only the static?

Comment: What is the command you are referring to?

Comment: I tried those commands but was not able to find anything to help me in this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This scenario sounds really weird because your setup should be working as you describe—and hope for it to work—if there is a static IP set in `/etc/network/interfaces`. That said, [this discussion on the official Raspberry Pi site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=111709) focuses on the issue with the user “rpdom” stating this on the post dated “Thu May 28, 2015 6:21 am”:

> This happens in the latest updates. It is caused by the new dhcp
>   client ignoring what the interfaces files does and doing its own thing
>   in addition... seems crazy to me. I'd look at how to reconfigure the
>   dhcp client (can't rememeber which it is or how to do it, I'm still on
>   the old one which works for me), disabling it, or removing it (if
>   possible).

Deeper in the thread user “KLL” suggests [the following other post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=798866#p798866) in their response dated “Mon Aug 10, 2015 12:59 pm.” According to “knute”:

> Somewhere along the way an upgrade modified my
>   `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the 'manual' word instead of dhcp
>   or static and I ended up with two IP addresses, my static one and a
>   dhcp address. I finally had time to play with it and found out that
>   `dhcpcd5` works differently than whatever was in it before. To get just
>   your static address, do not modify `/etc/network/interfaces`. Put back
>   the 'manual' word if you changed it and instead modify
>   `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` as shown in the example from the docs.

So the idea is that `dhcpcd5`’s behavior has changed in one of  the upgrades. And suggestion to solve the issue is to remove any changes from `/etc/network/interfaces` and instead adjust the settings in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to get a static IP address; example config below:

```
static <value>
             Configures a static <value>.  If you set ip_address then dhcpcd
             will not attempt to obtain a lease and just use the value for the
             address with an infinite lease time.

             Here is an example which configures a static address, routes and
             dns.
                   interface eth0
                   static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
                   static routers=192.168.0.1
                   static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

More info on the contents of `dhcpcd.conf` can be found [on the official man page for it](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.conf.5.html).

That said, another idea is to retain the settings you have in `/etc/network/interfaces` but then edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to add the line `denyinterfaces eth0` to tell the DHCP daemon to completely ignore `eth0`. Either solution should work, but one solution might be a more preferable solution depending on your overall networking needs/requirements.

Comment: My case was almost identical to one described here. Only difference was that my `/etc/network/interfaces` never got changed to `manual` like it was in Raspberry Pi forums case. Suggested solutions worked for me as well.

Comment: Same, where even with "static" I'm getting dhcp on my eth0. This is still an issue with a jessie-lite install. The workaround isn't helping me yet as I have a situation where I need the wlan0 interface to have a lower metric than the eth0 interface and I can't get dhcpcd5 to let me do that (so far).

Comment: A workaround that *did* work for me, however, was to tell dhcpcd5 not to look at eth0. This was done by adding "denyinterfaces eth0" in /etc/dhcpcd.conf.

Comment: This hasn't worked for me on jessie-lite, even following @PeterHansen 's suggested `denyinterfaces`. Solution for me was to reserve an address in the router's DHCP client pool. Shouldn't be the way to fix it, but as an interim fix, it seems OK.

Comment: A followup: in some cases I've found I had both dhcpcd5 and isc-dhcp-client installed, both assigning addresses. Furthermore, there's a systemd-initiated dhcpcd.service which runs on all interfaces (with options -q -b) as well as the dhcpcd5 process started by the "dhcp" option in network/interfaces. Sigh... fairly easy to solve once you know all that, I hope.

Answer (score 9):

what worked for me is using a /etc/network/interfaces as in the original question and simply removing the dhcp client:

```
apt-get remove dhcpcd5 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
```

Comment: In a scenario where you don't care about DHCP (or anything else dhcpcd can do) this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

The preferable way to disable any service such as dhcpcd is use the system management functions. You'll need to reboot for it take effect - unless you stop the service as well.

For Jessie (which uses `systemd` management):

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
```

And for the older Wheezy (`System-V` management):

```
sudo update-rc.d dhcpcd disable
```

But if you do disable it then you need to make sure you've got a static ip configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` otherwise your interfaces won't get an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

I must say that unfortunately none of the solutions proposed here worked for me. But after a long battle with DHCP, I was finally able to solve the problem:

```
vi /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
```

change:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

to:

```
[Network]
DHCP=no
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of what I needed to do for Raspbian Jessie 2017-01-11:

Edit /etc/network/interfaces and add the static address stanza, remove other references to the static interface (eth0 in this case). The auto line is important otherwise the interface will not start at boot:

```
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.44.17
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.44.27
```

Next disable dhcpcd and enable standard networking:

- Disable dhcpcd: `systemctl disable dhcpcd.service`
- Enable networking: `systemctl enable networking`
- reboot

Raspbian Jessie as of the 2017-01-11 release does not seem to use systemd's networking

Comment: dont forget nameservers

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few things and found that

```
 apt list --installed | grep dhcp
```

found:

```
dhcpcd5 
isc-dhcp-client
isc-dhcp-common
```

I just disabled `dhcpcd5` and that fixed it using:

```
 sudo apt-get remove dhcpcd5
```

did a reboot and all was dandy

Answer (score -1):

Removing the entire dhcp module or editing all kinds of config files feels to me kind of butchering, there should be a clean way. Windows, Debian, all have a nice GUI tool where you can check or uncheck DHCP, and simply add the fixed IP address, so why not on Raspbian?

In fact, the Raspberry Pi with Raspbian does have such a clean and simple tool. [Here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=67858) you will find info. The summary is that you can download and install apt package `network-manager-gnome`. This will install `NetworkManager` plus two front ends: `nmcli` and `nmtui`. The latter frontend is a text based dialog where you can deselect the auto option for a network connection (eth0 or wlan0) and enter the IP address, in an intuitive way, without having to look up command syntax.

Worked for me smoothly and successful.