# VMware guest static IP keep changing to DHCP

Tags: networking, debian, vmware-server

I inherited VM server with two guests (with Debian) running with static IPs (they work fine).

I created new guest (Debian 8.5) and configured it with static IP through `/etc/network/interfaces` in same way the other guests are configured (standard `iface eth0 inet static` etc).

On this guest once a 24h IP reverses to DHCP configuration but after restarting `eth0` it works with static IP again.

All guests are on the same vSwitch and in the same virtual network (connected to the same Physical Adapter).

I am managing VMs with vSphere Client 5.5.

`/etc/network/interfaces` on the guests:

This one is working correctly:

```
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.40
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

This one is keep going back to dhcp:

```
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [discussion and answers on this question](https://superuser.com/questions/985082/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-dhcp-client-in-raspbian-linux-on-a-rasperry-pi). That question is about Raspbian (the Rasperry Pi OS) but the general problem sounds the same. The solution seems to be disabling DHCP or adjusting the DHCP config to set the static IP there.

To set a static value to DHCP, just edit this file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and adjust the config like this example to force a static IP to the specified interface; in this case `eth0`:

```
static <value>
             Configures a static <value>.  If you set ip_address then dhcpcd
             will not attempt to obtain a lease and just use the value for the
             address with an infinite lease time.

             Here is an example which configures a static address, routes and
             dns.
                   interface eth0
                   static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
                   static routers=192.168.0.1
                   static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

To disable DHCP for a specific interface—like `eth0`—just edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and add this line to the config to force DHCP to simply not care about `eth0`:

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```